# how to load a .html page on QGraphicsWebView in Qt

Tags: qt

I have few .html pages. I want those pages to be invoked on click of some link.
I want those pages to be loaded from the server or else and not from local machine.
How do I do so?

Thanks

Comment: ui->webView->load(QUrl("http://www.stackovwerflow.com"));

I put two different addresses on buttons click slots and it works for me.